# search and replace only for first h2 tag in wordpress content

Tags: php

```
function add_content_after_h2($content){
    if (is_single()) {
        $div = "This content is after first h2 tag";
        $content = preg_replace('/(<\/h2>)/i', '\1'.$div, $content);
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_content_after_h2');
```

Using this code, the content is considering all H2 tag, but I need only first h2 tag to consider.

Comment: is it possible that h2 comes like this:- `<h2>` or `</h2>` also in your sentence? if yes then the above will not work

Comment: yes it is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `preg_replace()` a bit like below:-

```
<?php
$div = "This content is after first </h2> tag";
echo $content = preg_replace('/(h2 | <h2> | <\/h2>)/','', $div, 1);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/715312